# A handler for menu

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created the menu contribution in my [Eclipse RCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Rich_Client_Platform) application as an extension (`org.eclipse.ui.menus`). The items of this menu contribution are made as commands with handlers. I want to have such handlers not only for items (commands), but also for menus which are containing their items too (such as "File", "Edit"...).

The menus can have a field "commandID" in `plugin.xml`. I tried to create the command with this ID with a Handler extended the AbstractHandler, but it does't work.

Answer (score 1):

Menus can take commandIds so they can display a key shortcut.  That part is simply a display convenience.  There's still work to do behind the scenes to make the menu auto-popup.

See how the command `org.eclipse.ui.navigate.showInQuickMenu` is defined and used in the **org.eclipse.ui.ide** plugin.

It also has some supporting code in the `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder`:

```
    String showInQuickMenuId = IWorkbenchCommandConstants.NAVIGATE_SHOW_IN_QUICK_MENU;
    showInQuickMenu = new QuickMenuAction(showInQuickMenuId) {
        protected void fillMenu(IMenuManager menu) {
            menu.add(ContributionItemFactory.VIEWS_SHOW_IN
                    .create(window));
        }
    };
    register(showInQuickMenu);
```